# Отобразить раздел attach с иcпользованием xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Пытаюсь сделать почтовый клиент. Возникла проблема с xaml.

Когда я отправляю письмо, я бы хотел видеть UI что-то типа такого.

[image: ui]

Т.е. есть окошечко для текста и кнопочка добавления аттача. Если я добавил картинку то показывает, что добавилась картинка(мини-привью). Если видео то видео(можно просто статическую картинку).

Всё увязано с CList .String - cодержит путь до файла.

Как сделать xaml часть? Надо со скроллом.

Главная проблема с динамическим списком.

Comment: А в чём именно проблема с динамическим списком? `ObservableCollection<T>` + `ItemsControl` вполне решают.

Comment: Горизонтальный ItemControl? Можно примерчик? Желательно как можно ближе к task(е).

Comment: Он же настраивается! Пропишите в `ItemsContainer` `<StackPanel Alignment="Horizontal"/>`.